# override views-view-fields.tpl.php in custom module

Tags: views, hooks, theming

Hi i want to Override **views-view-fields.tpl.php** in our **custom module**. kindly help me by example.

Answer (score 5):

You need to define a [theme hook](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) for the field-template in your module and place a template in custom_module/theme/your-custom-template.tpl:

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_theme().
*/
function custom_module_theme($existing) {
  return array(
    'views_view_field__view_name__field_name' => array(
    'arguments' => array('view' => NULL, 'field' => NULL, 'row' => NULL),
    'template' => 'your-custom-template',
    'original hook' => 'views_view_field',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'custom_module') . '/theme',
   ),
  );
}
```

To narrow down which field-templates you want to replace you can name your return key to:

- views_view_field__view_name: Override all field templates of the view named "view_name"
- views_view_field__view_name__field_name: Override only this specific field

This example is taken from [grayside.org](http://grayside.org/2010/09/how-override-views-field-template-module)

Comment: great, then please mark the answer which helped you most as "accepted" to close this issue

Comment: For Drupal 8 this worked but instead of `arguments` you need `variables`. Also this question should specify for which version of Drupal this is.

Answer (score 1):

The view object is available in the tpl file, so by having an `if-else` statement it is possible to filter the views that need to the override by inspecting the name/display of the view.

A sample piece of code might help say for example using hook_field_attach_view_alter():

```
function MYMODULE_field_attach_view_alter(&$output, $context) {

  $field_name = 'test';
  $to_display = array('a');

  if (isset($output[$field_name]['#field_name'])) {
    if ($field_name == $output[$field_name]['#field_name']) {
      foreach ($output[$field_name]['#items'] as $delta => $item) {
        if (in_array($item['value'], $to_display)) {
          unset($output[$field_name][$delta]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```